Why nested inner span is taller than its outer span
Tailwind Playground
Let me use tailwind css for simplicity.
There are two HTML span elements, #outer and #inner.
<p class="font-mono">
  abc<span id="outer" class="relative"><span id="inner" class="absolute left-0 top-0">a</span>a</span>defg
</p>

I expect #inner overlaps with #outer, but instead the actual result shows that the painted characters of #inner is slightly lower than #outer:

Then I check the dev console and find outer's height is 19px, but inner is 24px.
Why does it happen? What's the correct way to make them overlap with each other?

Try removing left-0 top-0
<p class="font-mono">
  abc<span id="outer" class="relative"><span id="inner" class="absolute">a</span>a</span>defg
</p>

Result:

